# Is there any way to learn only the 'literal' meaning of the words?

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary

Is there any way to learn only the 'literal' meaning of the words?

I think language learners must learn directly the literal meaning of the words first before they know any derivative meanings.

I'd like to know whether there are any data or any sites for language learners to refer to for their grabbing the 'literal' meanings of English vocabulary.

Comment: Doesn't a dictionary give you that?  Or do you mean something different by "literal"?

Comment: @stangdon some words but not some other words

Comment: It would help if you can give us some examples of words and their dictionary definitions which you feel do not give us the literal meanings.

Comment: @stangdon Is there any good vocabulary book that I can refer to?

Comment: I think it would be a bad mistake to try to learn only the literal meanings of English words. ***All language is metaphor*** anyway, so it's not like the literal meanings (of those words where that's a meaningful concept) would help you understand much actual English text. But it's a "request for resources", which belongs on ELL Meta anyway.

Comment: Identifying which meanings are literal and which are figurative is largely a matter of opinion. For example, I am typing this comment in a "box" on my computer screen. Is that a literal box or a figurative one? It depends, and no one can give you a definitive answer.

Comment: I suggest you ask the people around you this question in **your own language**. Since all natural languages work the same way in terms of meaning, it would make no difference. This is not a question about English per se.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's just not about English.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan 'box' is a case usually in the shape of a rectangular or square and that image of it is important for language learnners to learn new words they don't know: I insist that image formation of a new word begins from 'literal' and 'one and only' way to master a foreign languae like English.

Comment: @gomadeng That is your opinion. Other people would say that the box on my computer screen is literally a box, too. (And if you think that the literal meaning must represent a physical object, there are plenty of ambiguities there, too.) Any list of only literal meanings would have to be very subjective.

Comment: @gomadeng A good example of a physical box is a "[sandbox](https://www.google.com/search?q=sandbox&tbm=isch)". It meets your definition of "box", but many people would say that it is not literally a box. It is very much a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer to your question is, no, there is no way to learn only the "literal" meaning of words. The reason is non-trivial and represents the edge of a very deep, lingo-philosophical rabbit hole. Consider: what is the literal meaning of the word "literal"? What exactly, in language, *is* meaning? Is a sentence some kind of "picture" of a state of affairs? Is meaning nothing more than the way some group of people *use* language among themselves? Is it in some sense akin to a more or less informal game?

However, more practically, if you replace "literal" with "dictionary" (as an adjective) then you'll probably get something like what you are after by simply -- literally, if you like -- using a dictionary. And a good one will give you an idea which, of multiple definitions, are most commonly in use.